# Appsheet calculated expired date spesifiec

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula, mobile-application, google-appsheet

I have an Appsheet who consist two column, let's both named is Production Date and Expired Date. If column Production Date has 2 years of Expired Date then how the formula in appsheet to calculated it? Let say the example, Production Date is 31/10/2023, therefore Expired Date is 31/10/2025. I want the formula to consider leap years.

Before that, i have created a formula but it is not worked. There was note "DATE function is used incorrectly"

[image]

Does anyone know the formula to solve this problem? Please let me know.

Comment: Have you considered using a string output instead like `YEAR([Production Date])+2&"/"&MONTH([Production Date])&"/"&day([Production Date])` ? Afterwards, convert it to a number value.

Comment: it worked for me, thank you Sir

Comment: Sir, i want to ask again, how if the production date has 35 month expired date. Is it formula like this? 


YEAR([Production Date]) & "/" & MONTH([Production Date])+35 & "/" & day([Production Date])

If i use it, it is not worked in appsheet.

Comment: That is good to hear, let me compose an answer based on my suggestion so hat others may easily see the answer. On your follow up question, I think the other way around is to use +2 on years and +11 on months to work since this method segregates the values of the year, month, and date. That is a good point though.

Comment: However, I can see a problem wherein an excess value, say excess months, cannot be carried over as an additional year since the output of this solution is a string. It can only be functional for year values.

Comment: yes sir, i still confusing due to excess month cannot be carried over as an additional year. If i modify your initial formula to "YEAR([Production Date]) & "/" & MONTH([Production Date])+35 & "/" & day([Production Date])", as example 31/10/2023, then the output will 31/45/2023.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Calculate a date two years from a given date**

Assume that the given date is 31/10/2023 and the value is in cell A2.

**DATE()**

- `=DATE(YEAR(A2)+2,MONTH(A2),DAY(A2))`
- equals 31/10/2025

**EOMONTH()**

- `=EOMONTH(A2,24)`
- equals 31/10/2025

---

**Calculate a date 35 months from a given date**

Assume that the given date is 31/10/2023 and the value is in cell A2.

**DATE()**

- `=DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+35,DAY(A2)-1)`
- equals 30/09/2026

**EOMONTH()**

- `=EOMONTH(A2,35)`
- equals 30/09/2026

---

**RESULTS**

[image: snapshot]

---